# skrollr cutting off site and being buggy on mobile iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, parallax, skrollr

I'm trying to use the skrollr library (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to create a website.
It works fine on standard browsers but for some reason cuts off and behaves strangely before and after orientation changes on mobile. 
I have it initialised at the bottom but it behaves as if it isn't. 
It cuts off about 2/3rds down on load then if I rotate back and forth it will go all the way and sometimes even adds too much space at the bottom then my logo animation at the top disappears. 
I have added some blank data commands within #skrollr-body so it knows where the end is but still no luck.

please help the example is here http://www.dalebailey.co.uk/idesignpixels/home.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems Scrollr calculates the height of it's content element and renders it accordingly. If you have images in the content with no declared height because you want them to be flexible to the browser it wont know the height until all the images are loaded. I managed to get over this problem by getting it to wait until all the images are loaded like so:

```
// Wait till all images are loaded before initiating the scrollr
var total_images = $("body img").length;
var images_loaded = 0;
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
        $("body").find('img').each(function() {
        var fakeSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $("<img>").attr("src", fakeSrc).load(function() {
            images_loaded++;
            if (images_loaded >= total_images) {
                // now all images are loaded.
                var s = skrollr.init();             
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```